Gas Estimation Error - Simple Token + ICO Project
I am a beginner in Solidity and created a simple token + ico file and am testing the code on Base Sepolia Testnet and am running into a peculiar error. I keep getting Gas Esimation Error on the buyTokens Function in my ICO contract which is leading to transaction failing. Tried using fixed hight value for Gas in Remix but still same error. Can anyone please help identify what is causing this ?
The code for the Token is as follows
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20, ERC20Burnable, Ownable {    
    uint256 private constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 100000000 * 10 ** 18;
    constructor() ERC20("TestToken", "TTA") Ownable(msg.sender) {
        _mint(msg.sender, INITIAL_SUPPLY);
    }

    /*function distributeTokens(address distributionWallet) external onlyOwner {
        uint256 supply = balanceOf(msg.sender);
        require(supply == INITIAL_SUPPLY, "Tokens already distributed");

        _transfer(msg.sender, distributionWallet, supply);
    }
    */
}

The Code for ICO is
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol"; // Import the IERC20 interface

//interface IERC20 {
//    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
//    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
//}

contract ICO {
    address payable public owner;
    IERC20 public token;
    uint256 public tokenPrice;
    uint256 public tokensSoldStage1;
    uint256 public tokensSoldStage2;
    uint256 public ICOEndTime;
    uint256 public stage1EndTime;
    uint256 public stage2EndTime;
    uint256 public target1;
    uint256 public target2;
    uint256 public rate1;
    uint256 public rate2;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    event TokensPurchased(address indexed buyer, uint256 amount, uint256 tokensSold);
    event ICOEnded(uint256 tokensSoldStage1, uint256 tokensSoldStage2, uint256 totalFundsRaised);

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only the owner can call this function");
        _;
    }

    constructor(
        IERC20 _token,
        uint256 _tokenPrice,
        uint256 _stage1Duration,
        uint256 _stage2Duration,
        uint256 _target1,
        uint256 _target2,
        uint256 _rate1,
        uint256 _rate2
    ) {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
        token = _token;
        tokenPrice = _tokenPrice;
        stage1EndTime = block.timestamp + _stage1Duration;
        stage2EndTime = stage1EndTime + _stage2Duration;
        target1 = _target1;
        target2 = _target2;
        rate1 = _rate1;
        rate2 = _rate2;
    }

    function buyTokens(uint256 _amount) external payable {
        require(block.timestamp < ICOEndTime, "ICO has ended");
        uint256 totalCost = _amount * tokenPrice;
        require(msg.value >= totalCost, "Insufficient funds");

        if (block.timestamp <= stage1EndTime) {
            require(tokensSoldStage1 < target1, "Stage 1 target reached");
            require(token.balanceOf(address(this)) >= _amount, "Insufficient tokens available for Stage 1");
            uint256 tokensToTransfer = _amount * rate1;
            require(tokensSoldStage1 + tokensToTransfer <= target1, "Stage 1 target exceeded");
            tokensSoldStage1 += tokensToTransfer;
        } else if (block.timestamp <= stage2EndTime) {
            require(tokensSoldStage2 < target2, "Stage 2 target reached");
            require(token.balanceOf(address(this)) >= _amount, "Insufficient tokens available for Stage 2");
            uint256 tokensToTransfer = _amount * rate2;
            require(tokensSoldStage2 + tokensToTransfer <= target2, "Stage 2 target exceeded");
            tokensSoldStage2 += tokensToTransfer;
        } else {
            revert("ICO has ended");
        }
        
        token.transfer(msg.sender, _amount);
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += msg.value;

        emit TokensPurchased(msg.sender, _amount, tokensSoldStage1 + tokensSoldStage2);
    }

    function endICO() external onlyOwner {
        require(block.timestamp > stage2EndTime, "ICO is still ongoing");
        uint256 totalFundsRaised = address(this).balance;
        owner.transfer(totalFundsRaised);
        
        emit ICOEnded(tokensSoldStage1, tokensSoldStage2, totalFundsRaised);
    }

    function withdrawTokens(uint256 _amount) external onlyOwner {
        require(token.balanceOf(address(this)) >= _amount, "Insufficient tokens available");
        token.transfer(owner, _amount);
    }

    function getCurrentStage() public view returns (uint256) {
    // Get the current block timestamp
    uint256 currentTime = block.timestamp;

    // Check if the current time is within Stage 1 duration
    if (currentTime < stage1EndTime) {
        return 1;
    }
    // Check if the current time is within Stage 2 duration
    else if (currentTime < stage2EndTime) {
        return 2;
    }    
    // If the current time is after all stages, return 0
    return 0;
    }

    function getCurrentStageTime() public view returns (uint256) {
    // Get the current block timestamp
    uint256 currentTime = block.timestamp;

    // Check if the current time is within Stage 1 duration
    if (currentTime < stage1EndTime) {
        return stage1EndTime;
    }
    // Check if the current time is within Stage 2 duration
    else if (currentTime < stage2EndTime) {
        return stage2EndTime;
    }    
    // If the current time is after all stages, return 0
    return 0;
    }

    function getCurrentStageTarget() public view returns (uint256) {
    // Get the current block timestamp
    uint256 currentTime = block.timestamp;

    // Check if the current time is within Stage 1 duration
    if (currentTime < stage1EndTime) {
        return target1;
    }
    // Check if the current time is within Stage 2 duration
    else if (currentTime < stage2EndTime) {
        return target2;
    }
    // If the current time is after all stages, return 0
    return 0;
    }
    function getCurrentStageTokensSold() public view returns (uint256) {
    // Get the current block timestamp
    uint256 currentTime = block.timestamp;

    // Check if the current time is within Stage 1 duration
    if (currentTime < stage1EndTime) {
        return tokensSoldStage1;
    }
    // Check if the current time is within Stage 2 duration
    else if (currentTime < stage2EndTime) {
        return tokensSoldStage2;
    }
    // If the current time is after all stages, return 0
    return (tokensSoldStage1+tokensSoldStage2);
    }

    receive() external payable {
        revert("Fallback function not allowed");
    }
}

Would really appreciate if someone could help me identify the error as I cant't seem to figure it out. (I already tried using Solidity 0.8.19 as mentioned in one of the other threads but the error persists)

ICOEndTime is always 0 so I think you should be reading a "ICO has ended" revert message. You should initialize that variable in the constructor.

Thank you for pointing it out. However despite initiating the ICOEndTime
ICOEndTime = stage2EndTime + _stage1Duration;
I still get the same error
